# Format HKBiologicalSex object returned by healthkit to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit

```
NSLog(@"gender %@", [[GSHealthKitManager sharedManager] readGender]);
```

The function as defined in `GSHealthKitManager.m` file

```
- (NSString *)readGender
{
    NSError *error;
    NSString *gender=[self.healthStore biologicalSexWithError:&error];

    return gender;
}
```

**Log**

```
2016-10-13 12:37:50.938 random[1712:58930] gender <HKBiologicalSexObject: 0x7b781320>
```

I want to display the biological sex in `UILabel`

Comment: Did you try reading the `biologicalSex` property? Which is a [`HKBiologicalSex`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/healthkit/hkbiologicalsex) enumeration, which specifies the biological sex chosen by the healthkit user?

Comment: @Petesh I looked into the return type and eventually figured out the solution. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"gender %@", [[GSHealthKitManager sharedManager] readGender]);
```

The function is redefined in GSHealthKitManager file as

```
- (NSString *)readGender
{
    NSError *error;
    HKBiologicalSexObject *gen=[self.healthStore biologicalSexWithError:&error];
    if (gen.biologicalSex==HKBiologicalSexMale)
    {
        return(@"Male");
    }
    else if (gen.biologicalSex==HKBiologicalSexFemale)
    {
        return (@"Female");
    }
    else if (gen.biologicalSex==HKBiologicalSexOther)
    {
        return (@"Other");
    }
    else{
        return (@"Not Set");
    }
}
```